# Running Python code in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to run the following Python code in Matlab:

```
from numba import autojit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.special import jv

def make_p(p_max):       
    p_list = []
    for p in range(p_max+1):
        temp = []
        for u in range(p+1):
            for r in range(p+1):
                for i in range(p+1):
                    if u+r+i == p:
                        temp.append([u,r,i])
        p_list.append(temp) 
    return p_list

@autojit 
def p_find(e,Ae,Aho,k,q,p_max,p_list):
    bessels_sqr_0 = (jv(0,Ae*k*q/2)*jv(0,Aho*k*q/4)*jv(0,Aho*k*q/4))**2    
    if bessels_sqr_0 > 0.99:
        return 0
    else:
        for i in range(1,len(p_list)):
            bessels_sqr = 0
            for triplets in p_list[i]:
                n,j,l = triplets[0], triplets[1], triplets[2] 
                bessels_sqr += (jv(n,Ae*k*q/2)*jv(j,Aho*k*q/4)*jv(l,Aho*k*q/4))**2
            if bessels_sqr_0 + bessels_sqr > 0.99:
                return i
            return p_max

@autojit
def integrand1(x,Dm,O_sqr,G_sqr,Dl,h,Ae,Aho,o_rf,o_ho,k,q):
    sum_func = 0
    for u in h:
        n,j,l = u
        sum_func += (O_sqr*(jv(n,Ae*k*q/2)*jv(j,Aho*k*q/4)*jv(l,Aho*k*q/4))**2)/(G_sqr+2*O_sqr*((jv(n,Ae*k*q/2)*jv(j,Aho*k*q/4)*jv(l,Aho*k*q/4))**2)+4*(Dl-o_rf*(n-l+j)-o_ho*(l+j)+Dm*x)**2)
    return (x/(np.pi*np.sqrt(1-x**2)))*sum_func

@autojit
def dEdt1(O_sqr,G_sqr,Dl,Dm,hb,h,Ae,Aho,o_rf,o_ho,k,q): 
    return -hb*np.sqrt(G_sqr)*Dm*quad(integrand1,-1,1,args=(Dm,O_sqr,G_sqr,Dl,h,Ae,Aho,o_rf,o_ho,k,q), epsabs = 1e-35)[0]  

@autojit
def integrand2(x,Dm,O_sqr,G_sqr,Dl):
    return (x/(np.pi*np.sqrt(1-x**2)))*(O_sqr/(G_sqr+2*O_sqr+4*(Dl+Dm*x)**2))

@autojit
def dEdt2(O_sqr,G_sqr,Dl,Dm,hb): 
    return -hb*np.sqrt(G_sqr)*Dm*quad(integrand2,-1,1,args=(Dm,O_sqr,G_sqr,Dl), epsabs = 1e-35)[0]  

def main():
    kb = 1.38064852e-23
    hb = 1.054571800e-34
    s = 0.5
    G_sqr = (2*np.pi*21.5e6)**2
    k = 2*np.pi/(422e-9)
    O_sqr = s*G_sqr/2 
    dt = 1e-5
    m = 87.9*1.660539040e-27 
    max_t = 2e-3
    tt = np.arange(0,max_t,dt)
    Dl = -2*np.pi*10e6
    T0 = 1

    E_array = np.zeros(len(tt))
    E_array[0] = kb*T0

    p_max = 5
    o_rf = 2*np.pi*26.51e6
    a = 0
    q = 0.1
    o_ho = o_rf/(2*np.sqrt(a+q**2/2))
    Ae = 1e-9

    p_list = make_p(p_max)          

    for i in range(len(E_array)-1):
        if i%int(len(E_array)/10) == 0:
            print(i/(len(E_array)-1)/10)         
        Aho = np.sqrt(2*E_array[i]/(m*o_ho**2))
        p_min = p_find(E_array[i],Ae,Aho,k,q,p_max,p_list)
        if p_min > 0:
            print(p_min)
            for h in p_list[:p_min+1]:
                if i < len(E_array):            
                    k1 = dEdt1(O_sqr,G_sqr,Dl,k*np.sqrt(2*E_array[i]/m),hb,h,Ae,Aho,o_rf,o_ho,k,q)
                    k2 = dEdt1(O_sqr,G_sqr,Dl,k*np.sqrt(2*(E_array[i]+(dt/2)*k1)/m),hb,h,Ae,Aho,o_rf,o_ho,k,q)
                    k3 = dEdt1(O_sqr,G_sqr,Dl,k*np.sqrt(2*(E_array[i]+(dt/2)*k2)/m),hb,h,Ae,Aho,o_rf,o_ho,k,q)
                    k4 = dEdt1(O_sqr,G_sqr,Dl,k*np.sqrt(2*(E_array[i]+dt*k3)/m),hb,h,Ae,Aho,o_rf,o_ho,k,q)
                    E_array[i+1] = E_array[i]+dt/6*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)                   
        else:
            if i < len(E_array):            
                k1 = dEdt2(O_sqr,G_sqr,Dl,k*np.sqrt(2*E_array[i]/m),hb)
                k2 = dEdt2(O_sqr,G_sqr,Dl,k*np.sqrt(2*(E_array[i]+(dt/2)*k1)/m),hb)
                k3 = dEdt2(O_sqr,G_sqr,Dl,k*np.sqrt(2*(E_array[i]+(dt/2)*k2)/m),hb)
                k4 = dEdt2(O_sqr,G_sqr,Dl,k*np.sqrt(2*(E_array[i]+dt*k3)/m),hb)
                E_array[i+1] = E_array[i]+dt/6*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)
    return E_array, tt, kb


start = time.time()
E_array, tt, kb = main()
end = time.time()
print('runtime: {:.3f}'.format(end-start))
plt.figure()
plt.title('Temperature vs time')
plt.plot(tt*1e3,E_array/kb, linestyle = '', marker = 'o', color='black')
plt.show()
```

The problem is, when I try to call `py.matcode.main()`, I get the following error message: Python Error:

> main() missing 14 required positional arguments: 'E_array', 'k', 'm',
>   'O_sqr', 'G_sqr', 'Dl', 'hb', 'kb', 'TD', 'method', 'p_list', 'o_ho',
>   'Ae', and 'p_max'

Even though Matlab is showing that Python has a problem running my code, the code runs fine in Python.

Moreover, I **am** able to call `py.matcode.make_p(py.int(5))` which gives the correct result.

Can anyone please help trying to find what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's interesting, since `main()` doesn't seem to require any arguments... Maybe try [`pyargs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pyargs.html) for the _required positional arguments_. Which MATLAB version is this?

Comment: @Dev-iL, since main() doesn't take any arguments, what will I use pyargs on? Moreover, as mentioned, python plays nicely with this code. Matlab version 2015a

Comment: Just go over the list of missing arguments and specify all of them... what else?

Answer (score 0):

Change the bottom of your code to:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    E_array, tt, kb = main()
    end = time.time()
    print('runtime: {:.3f}'.format(end-start))
    plt.figure()
    plt.title('Temperature vs time')
    plt.plot(tt*1e3,E_array/kb, linestyle = '', marker = 'o', color='black')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that didn't help. Does it fix the problem on your version of Matlab?